# Android Security Exception

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have been struggling with an issue for a while now and decided to post it here in the hope that someone can guide me in the right direction.

***Situation***

I have two separate applications:

- Alpha (com.droidbender.alpha)
- Beta (com.droidbender.beta)

Application **Beta** use an external advertisement SDK (provider Yume). This is a simple .jar library included in the building path and is located ./libs/YumeSDK.jar.

***Occuring error***

Several cases of a Security Exception have been reported on the PlayStore for the application **Alpha**

> java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent {
>   cmp=com.droidbender.beta/com.yume.android.bsp.YuMeUUIDService }
>   without permission not exported from uid 10041

The complete stack trace can be found below. It goes to the Yume SDK. The Yume SDK is not public and proguarded.

***Problem***

As you can see, the component name of the `Intent` that is fired from **Alpha** is actually targetting **Beta**.

**Alpha** does NOT have the Yume SDK implemented, has not included it in the project or isn't referencing to a Yume-related project whatsoever.

***Question***

I honestly have no idea why application **Alpha** fires the above `Intent`. The most answered I found which are related to Security were solved with the android:exported parameter but this didn't fix my issue. Does anyone have an idea? :)

Clean and Build does not help, in case you wondered.

***My Thoughts***

Application **Alpha** used to have the Yume SDK implemented but I took it out. I am 100% sure that there is nothing in code related to Yume anymore. Could it be that Eclipse magically keeps a reference to something magical in the magical building process?

***Extra information***

In the `Manifest.xml` of **Beta** we have the declaration of the Yume Service that listens to the appropriate action. This `Service` is started from inside the Yume SDK.

```
       <service
            android:name="com.yume.android.bsp.YuMeUUIDService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.yume.uuid.GETDEVICEUUID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Full stacktrace of the Security Exception shown by application **Alpha**:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent {
cmp=com.droidbender.beta/com.yume.android.bsp.YuMeUUIDService } without permission not exported from uid 10041 
at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1443) 
at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1425) 
at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:450)
at com.yume.android.bsp.r.e(Unknown Source) 
at com.yume.android.bsp.r.onServiceConnected(Unknown Source) 
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1131)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1148)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is there an admin area on the Yume site where you associate/configure your application/SDK access? I would check there if you haven't already. Just a guess.

Comment: No, there is no area for manual configuration. I also don't think that this is something to be configured outside of the SDK.

Comment: Odd. Have you opened up YumeSDK.jar - are there any configuration options in there? Did you happen to copy that jar from alpha to the beta project? :)

Comment: There was some copy pasting involved, both Alpha and Beta are based on Gamma (my first application). Gamma has Yume integrated, same as Beta but with other advertisement paramters. Alpha is stripped from the Yume SDK and implementation. Any thoughts :)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Yume at all but some providers do customise the jar you download from them with configuration information - however if there's no admin area on the Yume site (and no way to download a specific jar "for your app") it seems this is unlikely...

Comment: Ah, no there is no personalized SDK to download. There is just 1 sample application that has the YumeSDK.jar included and I just copy pasted the .jar file from there :). The SDK works though. It isn't a bug that can reproduced by any of my devices but I see it being submitted daily in the PlayStore :/